ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID from Puppeteer running in Docker
I am using Puppeteer within a Docker container to connect to a website that uses its own SSL certificate. I have done the following setup steps:

Install google-chrome-stable in my Docker image using the command recommended in the Puppeteer documentation.
Install my certificates to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates in my Docker container.
Point Puppeteer to use the installed version of Google Chrome when launching Puppeteer.

await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome' })


Attempt navigating to my page.

await page.goto('https://my-page-url')

However, when this code runs in the Docker container I get the following error:
net:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID at https://my-page-url

The ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID indicates that Chrome is unable to verify the SSL certificate for the site I am trying to reach. How can I make this error go away? I have seen that there are Chrome options such as --ignore-certificate-errors, but I would rather have Chrome successfully connect to the site using the certificate.

According to this superuser post, Chrome does not use the OS certificate store and instead uses its own. Once I followed the recommended steps to set up my own certificate store, I was able to connect to my site successfully. The updates I made were as follows:

Install libnss3-tools in my Docker image so that I can use the certutil tool. Documentation on the certutil tool can be found here.
Initialize the cert database to be used by Chrome.

RUN mkdir -p "$HOME"/.pki/nssdb && certutil -d "$HOME"/.pki/nssdb -N


Run the script to load the certs into the DB. Note that the script I used is a little different than the one in the superuser post.

CERT_PATH=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
cd $CERT_PATH

for i in *.crt ; do
  certutil -d sql:"$HOME"/.pki/nssdb -A -n "$i" -i "$CERT_PATH/$i" -t TCP,TCP,TCP
done

And to avoid any confusion, the TCP,TCP,TCP part has nothing to do with Transmission Control Protocol, it is the trust args for the cert where

T = trusted CA for client authentication (ssl server only)
C = trusted CA
P = trusted peer

(refer to the certutil docs for -t argument).
